# Spring Cloud: How to configure Hystrix in @FeignClient

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

I have following service:

```
@FeignClient(name = "person", fallback = FeignHystrixFallback.class)
public interface PersonService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/find", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    Person findPerson(@RequestParam("name") String name);
}
```

How to change the default timeout and thread pool size?

Comment: hi, hystrix is not defined in feignclient. FeignClient is just an interface for calling a real enpoint. Define hystrix in a controller, component,....

Comment: @duardito If so, why does `@FeignClient`'s `fallback=` property work?

Comment: fallback is a property from histrix, not hystrix itself. Fallback is a property, read this from documentation: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html. **Hystrix supports the notion of a fallback: a default code path that is executed when they circuit is open or there is an error.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other people that have run into this issue and have posted questions and have answers. The most relevant is this post:

[Feign builder timeouts not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571015/feign-builder-timeouts-not-working)

If you are wanting to manage the configuration of Feign you would want to check out the Feign documentation looking at the "configuration" attribute of the @FeignClient annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Set custom configuration for this interface

```
@FeignClient(name="person", configuration = FeignConfig.class)
```

and make configuration

```
public class FeignConfig {
    public static final int FIVE_SECONDS = 5000;

    @Bean
    public Request.Options options() {
        return new Request.Options(FIVE_SECONDS, FIVE_SECONDS);
    }
}
```